# Persistent names for usb-serial devices

Tags: raspbian, usb, serial

I am making a weather monitoring system to use Raspberry Pi 2. In weather eye, there are two sensors and two USB to serial ports.

I want persistent names for USB-serial devices.

I imitated [this link](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/), but serial number is same.[image]

```
ttyUSB0 - wind sensor
ttyUSB1 - temperature sensor
ttyUSB2 - USB to serial port (for Bluetooth)
ttyUSB3 - USB to serial port (for Bluetooth)
```

What do I need to do to implement this?

Comment: If the sensors or adapters do not have some form of unique information associated with them you probably cannot.

Comment: Show the other properties of these devices, i.e., VID, PID, device path.